How to include ./porebalzer < input.dat command in slurm file?
I am analyzing the pore size of my systems. Input parameters for the calculation is in input.dat and  porebalzer.exe file is required for the calculation.
I want to execute the ./porebalzer < input.dat command using a slurm file. After defining SBATCH options, how do we include the above command?

Unless your current directory is mounted on all cluster nodes, you can't. For this to work, input.dat needs to exist in the current working directory on the computer where Slurm actually ends up executing the job.

Assuming the two files porebalzer and input.dat reside on a common filesystem such as the home directory, you simply write the line after all the #SBATCH directives; e.g.
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
#SBATCH --mem=8G

./porebalzer < input.dat

The submission script is a regular shell script with added comments so any shell command you write is interpreted (nearly) as if it were typed at the command-prompt.
